# Running Rails on Apache2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, apache2, passenger

I have a linode server and was running a single website for dev purposes using webrick, now i want to put it into production and use Apache2 which I have installed and is up and running the classic It Work's! page which is expected.

Now I want to run multiple sites on this VPS I am using the current configuration which works fine for striaght HTML but will not run the web apps unless I run them on another port (rails s -p3500 etc) as port 80 is already taken up by Apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName datumpoint.bizmodev.com
  # ServerAlias *.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www.bizmodev.com
  <Directory "/var/www.bizmodev.com">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName homehounduk.co.uk
  ServerAlias *.homehounduk.co.uk
  DocumentRoot /var/www.homehounduk.co.uk
  <Directory "/var/www.homehounduk.co.uk">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Do i need to use passenger or something else to get this working? i have tried changing the virtual hosts to different ports and stuff but just end up getting a 403.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: passenger is a good idea

Comment: is there any tutorials on how to set it up from scratch?

Comment: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

you are telling to your apache that it will listen to anything on port 80

it you change to something like this:

```
<VirtualHost www.myawesomeurl.com:80>
```

in this case you are telling apache that everything that comes as a request from this address (`www.myawesomeurl.com`) on port 80 will use that options.

I think you want something like this:

```
# Basically your home, like: www.myhome.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName datumpoint.bizmodev.com
  # ServerAlias *.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www.bizmodev.com
  <Directory "/var/www.bizmodev.com">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# Your custom site
<VirtualHost www.something.com:80>
  ServerName homehounduk.co.uk
  ServerAlias *.homehounduk.co.uk
  DocumentRoot /var/www.homehounduk.co.uk
  <Directory "/var/www.homehounduk.co.uk">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and dont forget to point the `www.something.com` to the same ip as the `www.myhome.com`

Combine this with passenger and you will have one **server** running many rails apps and many php instances or html pages or anything you want.

Comment: Do i have to run rails server at all after this?

Comment: no, passenger will automatically start and maintain your rails server running

Comment: so if i delete the index.htm from the directories it should work?

but when i do it gives me -


Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at datumpoint.bizmodev.com Port 80

Comment: have you installed passenger? is passenger configured?

Comment: yes, passenger is installed, i also run - passenger start, looks like it is running as it gives the following - 


============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started ===============
PID file: /root/passenger.3000.pid
Log file: /root/passenger.3000.log
Environment: development
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0:3000/

You can stop Phusion Passenger Standalone by pressing Ctrl-C.

Comment: Have you configured your passenger with this http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_to_a_virtual_host_8217_s_root ?

Comment: yes, I am using that configuration, I am now getting a page with - Ruby (Rack) application could not be started - which means we are getting somewhere :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19212/discussion-between-nicos-karalis-and-robbie-done)